# How to use .h5 file in android studio?

Tags: python, android-studio, keras, hdf5, chaquopy

I'm trying to make a chatbot in my android app,
so I made it with python(with Keras and .h5 trained model) and linked it with android using chaquo but I'm still facing this error.
(I'm totally beginner), any help plz!

```
com.chaquo.python.PyException: OSError: Unable to open file (unable to open file: name = 'chatbot_model.h5', errno = 2, error message = 'No such file or directory', flags = 0, o_flags = 0)
```

I just notice that this is not just related to .h5 file, I add to a python directory all files beside .py file, and android can not see or open any file except .py file

Answer (score 0):

The current directory on Android is undefined, so you need to use the absolute path of your data file, as described in the [Chaquopy documentation](https://chaquo.com/chaquopy/doc/current/android.html#android-data):

> For example, if the data file is in the same directory as the Python file:
>
> ```
> from os.path import dirname, join
> filename = join(dirname(__file__), "filename.txt")
> ```

Comment: Is your data file in the same directory as the Python file that tries to load it? If so, please edit your question to include your code.

Comment: I just notice that this is not just related to .h5 file, I add to a python directory all files beside .py file, and android can not see or open any file except .py file

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you mean. In order for me to help you, please edit your question to include the full stack trace and the relevant code, and an explanation of where the relevant files are in your project.